# Convert C format string to C++ io manipulators

Tags: c++, iostream, manipulators

In C, I'm using printf("%+10.5d\n", x); to print the integer x.

I've written a small test case for C++ io manipulators, but the output has a different format:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
        int x = 3;
        printf("%+10.5d\n", x);
        std::cout << std::showpos << std::setw(10) << std::setprecision(5) << x << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
./testcommand
       +00003
           +3
```

Which io manipulator I am missing here to get the same output as with printf?

Comment: Or, you could avoid `<iomanip>` altogether and use [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/format/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

`std::setfill`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setfill/

with a short if statement
`((x>0) ? "+" : "" )`

so:
`std::cout << ((x>0) ? "+" : "" ) << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(10) << std::setprecision(5) << x << std::endl;`

Comment: Ups, my fault. c&p truncates the ' ' characters in the output. setfill fills all 10 charaters, not only 5.

Comment: setfill() won't do the job. It would fill the spaces on the left of + instead.

Comment: @cytrinox you were right please find the above answer corrected. Also note I would argue that since you are dealing with a whole different type of manipulator (the <iomanip> library instead of format strings) you are not going to get the same exact behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Using boost::format you can get what you're looking for in a more terse format.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/doc/format.html

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 3;
    std::cout << boost::format("%+10.5d") % x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For sprintf functionality you could change the cout line to this.

```
std::string x_string = boost::str(boost::format("%+10.5d") % x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get is this (note the `std::internal`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 3;
    printf("%+10.5d\n", x);
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::internal << std::showpos << std::setw(10) << std::setprecision(5) << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which is still not quite right:

```
    +00003
+000000003
```

but it's an improvement.

Comment: @cytrinox: well at least it might help to steer you in the right direction. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I don't think it's possible, at least
not without a lot of work.  In C++ (unlike in C), the
`precision` argument is ignored when outputting an integer, so
you can't obtain the effect you want using just manipulators
(and `boost::format` doesn't support it either).  You'll
probably have to format to a string, then prefix or insert the
`'0'` manually.

In the past, I had a `GB_Format` class (this was pre-namespace
days), a bit like `boost::format`, but which did support all of
the Posix formatting specifications; in order to make
`"%.<i>n</i>d"` work, I had to implement the integral
conversions myself, rather than using the underlying stream
conversions.  Something like the following:

```
std::string
fmtInt( int value, int width, int precision )
{
    unsigned            work = (value < 0 ? -value : value);
    std::string         result;
    while ( work != 0 || result.size() < precision ) {
        result += "0123456789"[ work % 10 ];
        work /= 10;
    }
    result += (value < 0 ? '-' : '+');
    while ( result.size() < width ) {
        result += ' ';
    }
    return std::string( result.rbegin(), result.rend() );
}
```